# How to update a child object with lookup relation on parent object?

Tags: trigger

Here is my code:

```
trigger UpdateChildBasedOnParent on LSDoctor__c (after insert, after update){


        List<LSPatients__c> childRecords = [Select DoctorToPatient__c, Doctor_Patient_Status__c FROM LSPatients__c WHERE DoctorToPatient__c IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];


        for(LSPatients__c child :childRecords){

            if(trigger.isInsert && child.Patient_Status__c == 'Cancelled'){
                child.Doctor_Patient_Status__c = 'Cancelled';
            }

            else if(trigger.isUpdate && child.Patient_Status__c == 'Cancelled' && trigger.NewMap.get(child.LSDoctor__c).Patient_Status__c != trigger.OldMap.get(child.LSDoctor__c).Patient_Status__c){
                child.Doctor_Patient_Status__c = 'Cancelled';
            }
        }


        if(childRecords.size() > 0)
            update childRecords;
}
```

Here LSPatients__c is a lookup relation on LSDoctor__c. I want to update the field Doctor_Patient_Status__c in LSPatients__c if the field Patient_Status__c='Cancelled' in LSDoctor__c.

The error message is:

> Compile Error: Field is not writeable:
>   LSPatients__c.Doctor_Patient_Status__c at line 10 column 17

Comment: what is the data type of the field that you are going to update?

Comment: Data type of both the fields is picklist

Comment: Have you looked at FLS for the Doctor_Patient_Status__c field for the profile getting the error?

Comment: @DominicBaker its read only. As it is a formula field. Sorry my wrong that i stated it is of type picklist.

Comment: You cannot write to a formula field, so you will receive an error when setting a value in APEX. You don't need a trigger for this because a formula field will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a formula field (or convert `Doctor_Patient_Status__c`) in `LSPatients__c`:

`DoctorToPatient__r.Patient_Status__c`